# How to create IQueryable collections?

Tags: .net, linq, iqueryable

I am new to Linq, though I was thinking of making use of LINQ expressions to query within the collections of my business objects.

We have created a new hierarchical set of models with several properties. Some properties have a `List<classx>`.  Would I be able to change the type to `IQueryable<classx>`? But then how would I add a new instance of classx to it?

Or should I create an `IEnumerable<classx>` instead?

Many Thanks for clarification,

Comment: Why do you not want to use List?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<classx>` already implements `IEnumerable<classx>` - LINQ to Objects doesn't need to use `IQueryable<T>`.

Unless you want to write your own querying routines with extra logic in (e.g. to use internal indexes etc) you should probably just use LINQ to Objects as it comes out of the box.

Comment: Thank you Jon. Thats great news. I will then stick to my Lists and use Linq to Object.

Comment: By the way to be sure I am doing this right, I would do my queries on IEnumerable<x> obj = from ... and return the obj as obj.ToList() to make it match my Property's type, correct?